# Delete Files in source directory if processing fails

Tags: mule

My requirement is to process a file at an inbound endpoint

**Use Case 1- Failure in processing the file**

If the file fails processing due to some exception like a validation error move the file to a separate directory different from the source. Delete the original file in the source directory

**Use Case 2 -Successful processing**

If the file processing is successful done , let the file remain in the source directory.

I tried the following , the file is moved to failed directory but the source file is not deleted as required in Use Case 1.

```
<flow name="InValidFlow1" doc:name="InValidFlow1">
<file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"  path="c:\filelanding\in2" pollingFrequency="100" connector-ref="input_2" moveToDirectory="c:\filelanding\in2" moveToPattern="#[header:originalFilename]-#[function:dateStamp]-Processed">
<file:filename-regex-filter pattern="(?!.*Processed|.*Failed)(.*)" caseSensitive="false"/>
</file:inbound-endpoint>
<test:component waitTime="20000"></test:component>
<custom-transformer class="com.XXX.XXX.service.ExceptionService" doc:name="Java"/>
<file:outbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="c:\filelanding\out2" connector-ref="output_2"/>
<exception-strategy ref="fot_exception_strategy_single" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
<file:connector name="error_output_1" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" doc:name="File"/>
<choice-exception-strategy name="fot_exception_strategy_single">
<catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(java.lang.RuntimeException)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
<!-- Mark the status as failed-->
<file:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="error_output_1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="c:\filelanding\backup2" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]-#[function:dateStamp]-Failed" >
</file:outbound-endpoint>
</catch-exception-strategy>
</choice-exception-strategy>
```

Do i need to override any existing mule functionality to achieve this behavior. The source folder on failure shouldn't contain the file. The destination folder should have the file marked with "Failed" status.

Comment: I don't see how use case 2 could work: if the file remains in the same directory, Mule will poll it again and again.

Comment: Thanks David ,Currently after processing i mark the file as processed and place in the same directory.At the file inbound endpoint i use a filename-regex-filter to skip the processed files. My issue is in case of an exception within the message flow , i need to move the file to a different directory from the source and delete the original file in source directory (Use Case 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For use case 1, in your exception strategy use the value in `originalFilename` in a MEL expression component to move the file to wherever you want.

You can use `org.mule.util.FileUtils.moveFileWithCopyFallback()` for that matter.

PS. `#[header:originalFilename]` is old style expression syntax, on Mule 3.3 and above use MEL `#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]`.

Comment: I used the FileUtils.moveFileWithCopyFallback(sourceFile, destinationFile) , in a java component defined in the exception strategy  but the source file is not deleted

Comment: So in the exception strategy i removed the file-outbound-endpoint and added a java component  <component class="com.XXX.XXX.service.RemoveUnprocessedFiles" doc:name="Java"/>

Comment: Any help on this, stuck on this problem since long

Comment: So `moveFileWithCopyFallback` copies but doesn't delete? If yes, that's probably because the file is still open by the inbound endpoint. If that's the case, in your Java component try using `IOUtils.closeQuietly()` on the payload, as I suspect its streaming content is what's holding the file open.